# Meteor call for sending image through api

Tags: image, file, api, meteor

Is it is possible to send image through meteor call to the API?

Client js

```
    var r = {image : image};
    Meteor.apply('callToServer', r, function(error, result){
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Server js

```
    Meteor.methods({
        uploadAndSaveToDB: function(data){
               var result = Meteor.http.post(apiUrl, { 
                              params: { image : data['image']}
                            });
               var result = JSON.parse(result.content);
               return result;
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about *how* to get the image data and send it to your api, it depends on a couple factors:

- How are you getting the image's data in the first place from your app (a submission form, a URL, some drawing library...)
- In what format does the API you are calling expects the image data to be sent (URL, raw data, encrypted...)

If you are simply asking if it is doable, then yes, definitely. You will just need to add the `http` package for this:

```
meteor add http
```

You can then make requests to your api pretty much like you wrote it. Just make sure to give the right name to your method call (also use `call` and not `apply` if you are not submitting an array of arguments):

Client js

```
var r = {image : image};
Meteor.call('uploadAndSaveToDB', r, function(error, result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

Server js

```
Meteor.methods({
    uploadAndSaveToDB: function(data){
           var result = HTTP.post(apiUrl, { 
                          params: { image : data['image']}
                        });
           var result = JSON.parse(result.content);
           return result;
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was actually sending the array. And when I send normal image through the call it is not fully transferring to the function  "uploadAndSaveToDB: function(data){" . It is sending as File object from Meteor.call. But when I console the value of image from Meteor.methods it is just giving as null object. No file values are getting.

Comment: Anyways I managed to send the image by passing only '.src' value of file input. But I need to know whether we can send images as we send in PHP